# Mangeto Shipping not applying

Tags: magento

We have recently upgraded magento version 1.4 in to 1.7.2.After we upgraded it now shipping seems not working properly.

We only have a standard shipping rate and free shipping (if the amount is more than 2500 its free).

Just compared with with old 1.4 site backup and all shipping settings and configurations are exactly same.

New upgraded site, when I come to shipping page its showing me both Standard and free one (I can select one of these).
Even if the total is more than 2500.

but old site its only showing one shipping rule based on amount.Either free or standard one.

You guys have any idea about that?

Thanks

Comment: have you used table rates in old setup ?

Comment: No I dont have any table rates